# PHP language redirection can't switch back

Tags: php

I have a very simple static one-page website, which I have available in English (default) and also in German - what I would like to achieve is to automatically redirect German users to the German version of the website which seems to work with the code I use here:

```
        <?php
        $lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
        switch ($lang){
            case "de":
                header("Location: http://www.website.net/de");
                break;      
        }
        ?>
```

The problem now is that I still would like to give them the option to switch to English as well however once they click English they will always be redirected to German version of the site and are stuck with it. Is there a way to have this fixed and working properly?

Comment: You need an additional selector/override. Set a cookie and prioritize it over the header. Btw, that's not how `Accept-Language` works - it's case-insensitive, may contain `EN;q=0.1, DE-AT; q=1.0` for instance, so cutting out two letters works by accident at best.

Comment: you can detect browser language by checking the user agent, then set a cookie for the language detected. put a select language menu at the top page and serve lang based on cookies

Answer (score 0):

You need another variable. You can do it with a URL param or a cookie, either way will get you what you want.

Comment: Hi b729sefc - thank you very much for your answer. Could you please help me more about the URL param part and how to have that implemented in my current script?